# Indoor positioning of a moving object in 3D space

Tags: algorithm, indoor-positioning-system

I am working on a project which determines the indoor position of an object which moves in 3D space (e.g. a quadcopter).

I have built some prototypes which use a combination of gyroscope, accelerometer and compass. However the results were far from being satisfactory, especially related to the moved distance, which I calculated using the accelerometer. Determining the orientation using a fusion of gyroscope and compass was close to perfect.

In my opinion I am missing some more sensors to get some acceptable results. Which additional sensors would I need for my purpose? I was thinking about adding one or more infrared cameras/distance sensors. I have never worked with such sensors and I am not sure which sensor would lead to better results.

I appreciate any suggestions, ideas and experiences.

Comment: GPS and/or video are standard as far as I know.  Though I suppose that if you just needed to do distance checking within a closed space, some kind of laser measurement and/or echo sensor would work, theoretically.

Answer (score 1):

The distance checking would decidedly help. The whole algorithm of any surface geo survey is based on the conception of start/final check. You know the start, then you add erroneous steps, and come to the finish that you know, too. But you have collected some sum error by the way. Then you distribute the error found among all steps done, with the opposite sign, of course.

What is interesting, in most cases you not only somewhat diminish the effect of arbitrary mistakes, but almost eliminate the systematical ones. Because they mostly are linear or close to linear and such linear distribution of found error will simply kill them.

That is only the illustration idea. Any non-primitive task will contain collecting all data and finding their dependencies, linearizing them and creating parametrical or correlational systems of equations.  The solving of them you get the optimal changes in the measured values. By parametrical method you can also easily find approximate errors of these new values.

The utmost base of these methods is the lesser squares method of Gauss. The more concrete methodics can be found in old books on geodesy/geomatic/triangulation/ geodesy nets. The books after introduction of GPS are for nothing, because everything was terribly simplified by it. Look for the books with matrix formulaes for lesser squares solutions.

Sorry if I had translated some terms into English with errors.